# How to Add Previously Stored Data in Elasticsearch index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6, bonsai-elasticsearch

hope you are fine!

I have implement elasticsearch Locally & also in production on Heroku but I face a problem on Heroku that when I create an index by

```
curl -XPUT https://your:bonsai@url-here.us-east-1.bonsai.io/blogs-blogs
```

I can search from the records which are newly added after making the index but not able to search from the records which I save before this index.

Comment: Where did you "add" your records before your create your index ?

Comment: i save my record in my Postgres database on Heroku  using Postgres addons

Comment: so you have to load your history in Elasticsearch. Usually frameworks add trigger on an entity Create/Update/Delete. But you have to Batch insert the history. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: it's mean there is no other way first I have to delete my records then add them again by batch insertion?

Comment: Of course you don't have to delete your records from postgres. You juste have to write a script to init your history. If it's to complicated, just touch all your data with your entity, but it will update your updated_at date also. So you should just write your initialisation script.

Comment: thankyou @Jaycreation I'll try this  & Thankyou for the help <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to import your models in elasticsearch you can easily done by the following line

```
heroku run bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Post' FORCE=true
```

But make sure your Bonsai and other Es gems should be compatible with elasticsearch.